# PHP Regex to split name and address

Tags: php, regex, split

I have string like this `May Business Park E2 No. 12, Jakarta, Indonesia 11620 +6281932539817` and my regex is `(.*)\b\d{5}\b([\d\+\s\(\)\-\/]{7,})` but it gives me :

`May Business Park E2 No. 12, Jakarta, Indonesia`

`11620` -> split the zipcode

`+6281932539817` -> split the phone number

As you can see that the name and address not split as I expected. What did I miss? and also, I use the country code in phone number, any better ideas?

Comment: Which one is `name`?

Comment: Are you splitting or matching? Can you please add the significant part of your code?

Comment: `May` is the name. I am using regex to determine which the name, address, zip code, and phone number in one sentence @choz

Comment: Can you give more string sample than the one above? For me, it's hard to read the pattern for what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: *not split as I expected* - and what *is* expected? Also, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL6rO0/1) just in case. I do not think it is possible to have the regex engine disambiguate the name from address. It is not something a regex can handle.

Comment: say, I have the string `myfullname myfulladdressblablabla zipcode phonenumber` I expected the name and address split @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: What are the specs for the `myfullname`? What about `Сергей Петрович Черных`? `Jędrek Król`? There is no way unless there are clear requirements.

Comment: since it is for indonesia only, it will be just [a-z] @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: thanks for your example, but what if user has 2 or more words for their name? should I add special character to separate name and address? what is your solution? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: So, you have a list of all Indonesian first, second,... last names? Again, regex does not tell a human name from a street name (and sometimes, they are the same, right?). I am driving at a conclusion that it is not possible unless you have a certain formatting that you can rely on, or a full list of alternatives that may appear as names (however, that regex pattern may be too long). If I had a solution, I'd have posted it already, but there is none, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows as the number of characters in the zipcode and the phone number are constant throughout all the data you are going to process

```
var str = "May Business Park E2 No. 12, Jakarta, Indonesia 11620 +6281932539817";
var lastTwenty = id.substr(id.length - 20); 
//This will give you "11620 +6281932539817"
var phoneNumber = id.substr(6,19); 
//This will give you the phone number "+6281932539817"
var zipcode = lastTwenty.substr(0,4);
//This will give you the zipcode "11620"
```